# Выводится число без запятой (Нужно 102,01 вместо 10201)

Tags: c#

На выходе нужно получить 102,01 а выходит 10201 без запятой.

```
public static double Calculate(string userInput)
    {
        var parts = userInput.Split(' ');
        var Initial = double.Parse(parts[0]);
        var Percent = double.Parse(parts[1]);
        var Months = double.Parse(parts[2]);
        double result = (double)Math.Pow(Initial * (1 + Percent/12 / 100), Months);
        return result;
    }
public static void Main()
    {
        double c = Calculate("100 12 2");
        Console.WriteLine(c);
    }
```

Comment: Судя по формуле оно и должно быть без запятой. Смотрите верно ли вы формулу записали.

Comment: Попробуйте так double c = Calculate("10 12 2");

Comment: Распишите как можно подробнее что именно Вы пытаетесь расчитать. Сейчас мы видим неправильную формулу и сложно понять как должно быть правильно.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Судя по всему, Вы пытаетесь расчитать сумму, которая набежит с накоплением процентов за заданное количество месяцев.

Если так, то скорее всего у Вас ошибка в формуле. В степень нужно возвести только часть «один + процент», начальную сумму не нужно. Вот так получится 102,01:

```
double result = Initial * Math.Pow(1 + Percent/12 / 100, Months);
```

P.S. В таких случаях нужно как можно подробнее описывать условие задачи. Сейчас в вопросе нет информации о том, что рассчитывается и поэтому сложно понять, получилась ли у меня правильная формула или нет.

P.P.S. Если это попытка рассчета сложных процентов, то и исправленная формула и результат вызывают сомнения: 12% годовых и 1% месячных это разные вещи.

Comment: Я тут новичок. Исправлюсь. Вы правы, это расчет суммы с накоплением процентов. Вопрос уже разрешился, спасибо. Пользователь tym32167 навел на мысль и ошибка действительно была в записи формулы.